# Jquery class selector not triggering when a addClass has been used

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors

The following code adds a class to a DIV called 'shift' among other things.

```
$('.adminopen').click(function(){
        $('.backoffice').addClass('open');
        $('.maincontent').addClass('shift')
        return false
    });
```

Once this class has been added why does the next script also contained in the initial document ready section not trigger.

```
$('.shift').click(function(){
        $('.backoffice').removeClass('open');
        $('.maincontent').removeClass('shift');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because shift is not present in DOM when you are binding event to shift

You need to use event delegation -

```
$(document).on('click','.shift',function(){
        $('.backoffice').removeClass('open');
        $('.maincontent').removeClass('shift');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you're only binding to the initial elements. Use delegation with [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) :

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.shift', function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use event delegation as suggested above, or bind the event handlres right when you assign class.

```
function bindShift() {
    $('.shift').click(function () {
        $('.backoffice').removeClass('open');
        $('.maincontent').removeClass('shift');
    });
}

$('.adminopen').click(function () {
    $('.backoffice').addClass('open');
    $('.maincontent').addClass('shift');
    bindShift();
    return false
});
```